# Javascript and DOM manipulation efficiency on RPi Win10 IoT

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, background, raspberry-pi

## Background

I've created a slideshow application with asp.net (C#) and html5/css3/javascript (w/ a bit of jQuery). I'm trying to display this on a Raspberry Pi 2 device running Windows 10 (IoT version) inside the Windows Universal WebView component.

I'm having issues with slides lagging. My slideshow is based off of one div with 3 background images:

1. The **top image** is the slide image. Displayed with `background-size: contain`.
2. The **middle image** is a transparent gradient meant to lay over the bottom image for affect.
3. The **bottom image** is server generated on image upload and is a zoomed and blurred image meant to give a kind of gradient splash mapping of color hot zones. Any image artifacts left from this process are smoothed by image #2.

## Problem

I switch the background image with one line of code:

```
slide.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + slides[slideIndex % slides.length] + "), " +
                              "url(../images/egg-shell.png), " +
                              "url(" + blurred[slideIndex % blurred.length] + ")";
```

Works great in my browser, however, on the Raspberry Pi the **bottom image** with **middle image** overlayed displayed way before the **top image**.

## Abnormalities

I have had to do a couple things to make this work with the Raspberry Pi and Webview component, I only list these because they *might* be causing my problem:

- After changing the background image, I have to set the slide element's display property to none, then back to block to redraw the background image else it won't change.
- I'm preloading images by loading a bunch of JS `Image` objects with paths specified by webservice, then waiting for each image to finish reporting `.onload` to start the slideshow.

---

The whole application is pretty lightweight. If needed I can provide it but there must be something simple I'm missing. I don't know the efficiency if I were to load each image in a separate `<img>` element and then set z-indexs. Nor do I know if the efficiency would increase by letting the images load in separate slides behind the current one. This is why the question is asking about DOM manipulation and Javascript. At any rate, thanks for reading this long explanation and hopefully you can help!

Comment: If you're pre-loading everything anyway why not just use one element per slide?  That also gives you all sorts of nice options for transitioning between slides.

Comment: How would I transition for the best performance? Translate3d would take advantage of hardware acceleration but might be too hard on the RPi compared to z-index. But I don't know about either.

Comment: The 'best' depends on the implementation of the WebView which you might have to experiment with.  For an instant transition, you'd [request an animation frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and, within the callback, hide the last slide and show the next using CSS, probably.  I can write up a quick example if that's not clear.

Comment: Please do I'll give it a try to see if it works. Keep in mind that the Windows Universal WebView component renders in IE11 documents mode (with a few caveats). Css3 animations run extremely slow on the RPi. Most of the solutions I explored that were feasible failed one of these two categories (IE11 compatibility or efficient enough for RPi).

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/utwqsb45/ or if you prefer

```js
$(function($){

var $slides = $('.slide');
  
function transition(){
    var $current = $('.slide.showing'),
        $next = $('.slide[data-number="' + parseInt($current.data('number') + 1) + '"]');
    if (!$next.length) {
        $next = $('.slide[data-number="1"]');
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      $current.removeClass('showing');
      $next.addClass('showing');
    });
}
  
setInterval(transition, 1000);

})($);
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 99%;
  height: 99%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slide.showing {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide showing" data-number="1">one</div>
<div class="slide" data-number="2">two</div>
<div class="slide" data-number="3">three</div>
```

Comment: I already have something very similar to this and it doesn't work. I'm not having problems making the slideshow work. I'm having problems making the images in the slideshow (which are stacked using CSS3 multiple backgrounds) load all at once, even with the preloading, it seems that drawing the image takes too long.

Comment: Have you tried stacking them by simply absolutely positioning three images in a container?

Comment: Yes that wouldn't work though because the images have dynamic sizes so centering the main slide image would be extremely difficult. I ended up dropping the middle image, and setting the bottom element to have position absolute and then the top image to be display block with max-width and max-height to `100%` and margin: auto! Still having issues with performance though. I'm going to try load-event driven actions (which I've already done but I'm going to refactor a couple more times lol)

Comment: Oh, you can center plain images in a set-width container: http://jsfiddle.net/oLv6L99q/  I think the bigger problem would be tricking the WebView into pre-loading the images into whatver buffer it draws from, which might be possible if you make them 'visible' off-screen (like at top: -1000px) and then move them into view?  Maybe?